# Fetch data between tags from failed xml in oracle

Tags: xml

I have below XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SyncConsumer xmlns="http://www.ford.com/oagis" xmlns:oa="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" environment="Test" revision="1.7" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ford.com/oagis C:\VCC_Workspace\gca_D14.07\gca_xsd\src\main\resources\Consumer\Ford\BODs\SyncConsumer.xsd">
<oa:ApplicationArea>
<oa:Sender>
<oa:LogicalId>Volvo</oa:LogicalId>
<oa:Component>Vista</oa:Component>
<oa:Task>SyncConsumer</oa:Task>
<oa:AuthorizationId>MQTEST27</oa:AuthorizationId>
</oa:Sender>
<oa:CreationDateTime>2016-07-05T12:23:47Z</oa:CreationDateTime>
<oa:BODId>mq-test-027</oa:BODId>
</oa:ApplicationArea>
<DataArea>
<oa:Sync confirm="Always">
<oa:SyncCriteria>
<oa:SyncExpression action="Add"/>
</oa:SyncCriteria>
</oa:Sync>
<Consumer>
<ConsumerHeader>
<ResponseTemplate Name="VistaSyncConsumer">
</ResponseTemplate>
<Source>AU</Source>
</ConsumerHeader>
<ConsumerDetails Category="Person">
<PersonDetails>
       <[FirstName>Test_data_027</FirstName>
           <Surname>testdata_027</Surname>
</PersonDetails>
<EmailAddress Active="true" Usage="Home">no_email@volvocars.com</EmailAddress>
</ConsumerDetails>
</Consumer>
</DataArea>
</SyncConsumer>
```

Context : when i upload this XML it gets failed due to :
<[FirstName>Test_data_027

invalid [ in firstname

Even if the xml contains this kind of invalid character, can i fetch the EMail address from this XML via SQL query

I HAVE BEEN USING THE BELOW CODE TO EXTRACT THE DATA.
THE ABOVE XML IS PRESENT IN CLOB COLUMN OF TABLE XML_MESSAGE :
--select * from xml_message_335 where message_no=811862794;

```
select MESSAGE_NO,
           SENDING_RECEIVING_SYSTEM,
           SENDING_USER,
           BOD_ID,
           CREATION_DATE,
           EMAILID,
           ContactNumber
      from (
select xml_main.MESSAGE_NO,
                   xml_main.SENDING_RECEIVING_SYSTEM,
                   xml_main.SENDING_USER,
                   xml_main.BOD_ID,
                   xml_main.CREATION_DATE,
 x.EmailAddress as EMAILID,
 null as ContactNumber
 -- , x.ContactNumber as ContactNumber
from xml_message_335 xml_main
   , xmltable(
       xmlnamespaces(
         default 'http://www.ford.com/oagis'
       , 'http://www.openapplications.org/oagis' as "oa"
     
       )
     , '/SyncConsumer/DataArea/Consumer/ConsumerDetails/EmailAddress' 
       passing xmltype(xml_main.orig_message)
       columns  EmailAddress      varchar2(64) Path '.' 
     ) x 
      where /*trunc(CREATION_DATE) between trunc(start_date_exec) and trunc(end_date_exec)
 --and  failure='N'
     -- and message_no = 811862822
      and*/ message_no = 811862794
      )
      where  EMAILID is not null;
```

BUT IT GIVES ME ERROR SAYING : LPX-00231: invalid character